# How to export objects as gltf?

Tags: python

I want to export objects from the active collection as gltf file.

But it's not exporting any object in the gltf file and the file size is 1kb

Code-

```
import bpy
import os


filepath = "C:/Users/karan/Desktop/"

override = bpy.context.copy()
override['selected_objects'] = bpy.context.collection.objects

with bpy.context.temp_override(**override):
    bpy.ops.export_scene.gltf(
        filepath=os.path.join(filepath, f'{bpy.context.collection.name.strip()}.gltf'),
        export_format='GLTF_EMBEDDED',
        use_selection=True
    )
```

I am getting this error

`19:51:36 | INFO: Draco mesh compression is available, use library at c:\Users\karan\Downloads\Blender\stable\blender-3.3.7+lts.659c307f2502\3.3\python\lib\site-packages\extern_draco.dll 19:51:36 | INFO: Starting glTF 2.0 export 19:51:36 | INFO: Finished glTF 2.0 export in 0.007512092590332031 s`

Comment: It's not exporting any object

Comment: Could you edit the question so it reflects the problem better?

Answer (score 0):

The export operator seems to ignore context override. Luckily it can export active collection on  its own:

```
import bpy
import os


filepath = "C:/Temp"

bpy.ops.export_scene.gltf(
        filepath=os.path.join(filepath, f'{bpy.context.collection.name.strip()}.gltf'),
        export_format='GLTF_EMBEDDED',
        use_active_collection =True
    )
```

[See the docs for more](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.export_scene.html#bpy.ops.export_scene.gltf)

Comment: but I want to export from the list of collections by looping

Comment: You should provide all the relevant information in the question.

Comment: Maybe put the collections you want in another collection temporarily and use `use_active_collection_with_nested `

Comment: do you know why it's ignoring context override, is it a bug?

Comment: I though if I manage to export from one collection then it will be easy to do for others by looping. That's why I did mention that.

Comment: I don't really understand why, but looking at the add-ons code it seems like export operators are maybe somehow different than other operators... Just guessing. But they also seem to have suspiciously a lot of functionality almost as if it's deliberate workaround for not working with context overrides...

Comment: But fbx and obj export operator works fine